# Ansible and Git Permission denied (publickey) at Git Clone

Tags: git, ansible

I have a playbook where I am trying to clone from a private repo (GIT) to a server.

I have setup ssh forwarding and when I ssh into the server and try to manually clone from the same repo, it successfully works. However, when I use ansible for the to clone the repo to the server, it fails with "Permission Denied Public Key".

This is my playbook `deploy.yml`:

```
---

- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
      - name: Setup Git repo
        git: repo={{ git_repo }}
             dest={{ app_dir }}
             accept_hostkey=yes
```

This is how my `ansible.cfg` looks:

```
[ssh_args]
ssh_args = -o FowardAgent=yes
```

I am also able to perform all the other tasks in my playbooks (os operations, installations).

I have tried:

- Specifying sshAgentForwarding flag in `ansible.cfg` on the server (ansible.cfg in same dir as playbook) using:

  > ssh_args = -o ForwardingAgent=yes
- used `become: false` to execute the git clone
- running `ansible -i devops/hosts webservers -a "ssh -T git@bitbucket.org"` returns:

  `an_ip_address | UNREACHABLE! => {
      "changed": false,
      "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
      "unreachable": true
  }`

This is the command that I use to run the playbook:
`ansible-playbook devops/deploy.yml -i devops/hosts -vvvv`
This is the error message I get:

```
fatal: [162.243.243.13]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote '' -h refs/heads/HEAD", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"accept_hostkey": true, "bare": false, "clone":
 true, "depth": null, "dest": "/var/www/aWebsite", "executable": null, "force": false, "key_file": null, "recursive": true, "reference": null, "refspec": null, "remote": "origin", "repo": "git@bitbucket.org:aUser/aRepo.git", "ssh_opts": null, "track_submodules": false, "update": true, "verify_commit": false, "version": "HEAD"}, "module_name": "git"}, "msg": "Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not r$ad from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote r$pository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: Sometimes when you update your Mac, your key stops working (at least for me). I had to `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` again and then it worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By reading the documentation for ssh forwarding in ansible. I was able to figure out the solution.

The problem was that my ssh keys were not being forwarded because Ansible does not by default forward your keys, even if you have set up the key forwarding in `~/.ssh/conf` (I updated my question with the `ansible.cfg` that I had before fixing the issue).

The solution was to add `transport = ssh` to `ansible.cfg` under `[defaults]` plus running `ansible-playbook` from the location where `ansible.cfg` is located and make sure that the following setting exists in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the target box:

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

My `ansible.cfg` now looks like this:

```
[defaults]
transport = ssh

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

Comment: How do I ask Ansible-playbook to take this file into account.  Like for ex: `ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local GitClone.yaml`.  Where and how do I include the cfg file?

Comment: The cfg file is included automatically once you run the `ansible-playbook -i hosts <a_playbook>.yml`. You should put the cfg file inside the same directory as you playbook to be run. Also make sure you run `ssh-add` before you run the `ansible-playbook`.

Answer (score 5):

To clone the private github repo over the remote server, I am doing this:

First add the ssh key to your ssh-agent:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my-private-key.pem
```

After that I have modified the `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
transport = ssh
sudo_flags = -HE

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

Now you can clone the github private repo even as root user

Normally, I also add these two tasks in my playbook/roles tasks as well:

```
- name: Tell the host about our servers it might want to ssh to
  known_hosts:
    path: '/etc/ssh/known_hosts'
    name: 'github.com'
    key: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org') }}"

- name: Upload sudo config for key forwarding as root
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/sudoers.d/ssh_key_forward
    line: 'Defaults env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK'
    create: yes
    owner: root 
    group: root 
    mode: "0440"
    state: present
    validate: 'visudo -c -f %s'
```

Strange, it work for me. If the `ssh` option didn't work for you then you can use the username/password option like this:

```
- name: Pull the code
  git:
    repo: "https://{{ bitbucket_login }}:{{ bitbucket_password|urlencode }}@bitbucket.org/path/project.git"
    dest: /var/www/myproject
    version: master
```

Hope that might helpful for you and others

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work either. I was able to make it work by using `transport = ssh` in the `ansible.cfg` `[defaults]`.

Comment: @lv10 I have added another option, please check that.

Comment: `ssh-add` made it work for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

For public repository : (you can use https)

```
- name: Git checkout ghq from github
  git:
    repo: https://github.com/x-motemen/ghq.git
    dest: /tmp/ghqt
    depth: "1"
```

For private, you can copy your private ssh key before and attach like this

```
- name: Git checkout dotfiles repo
  git:
    repo: "https://github.com/x-motemen/ghq.git"
    dest: /tmp/ghqt
    version: "develop"
    accept_hostkey: yes
    key_file: "{{ ssh_key_private_remote_path }}{{ ssh_key_private_filename }}"
```

More details : https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/cloning-private-github-repositories-ansible-on-remote-server-through-ssh

Answer (score 1):

On a localhost-only -scenario `ForwardAgent` is completely useless, as it would forward the agent only to a remote host.

Even if `git` works from command-line when run manually, it doesn't work from Ansible no matter what. The only working solution I found was to convert `git` into `command`, like:

`- command: /usr/bin/git clone git@github`

Comment: This is not a good solution but it will required lots more tasks.  The git module should work but I cannot get it to work over ssh.  My ansible scripts work find with svn and ssh.